Observing related data from a SwiftData model fetched by @Query
I'm using SwiftData in a test project to see what it's like and determine if it's something I can use in a future project. While test actual app is fairly simple, I did extract an even smaller example code to show my issue.
It's a modified version of the default sample project you get in Xcode, that creates items with a Date. I added one model, Category. Each Item now belongs to a Category:
@Model
final class Category {
    var name: String
    var items: [Item] = []
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Category.items)
    var category: Category
    
    init(timestamp: Date, category: Category) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.category = category
    }
}

I show the categories and the numbers of items in an view:
struct Categories: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Query var categories: [Category]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(categories) { category in
            NavigationLink {
                CategoryDetail(category: category)
            } label: {
                HStack {
                    Text(category.name)
                    Spacer()
                    Text("\(category.items.count)")
                }
            }
            .swipeActions(edge: .leading) {
                Button("Add", systemImage: "plus") {
                    modelContext.insert(Item(
                        timestamp: Date(),
                        category: category
                    ))
                }
                .tint(.green)
            }
            .swipeActions {
                Button("Remove", systemImage: "trash") {
                    if let lastItem = category.items.last {
                        modelContext.delete(lastItem)
                    }
                }
                .tint(.red)
            }
        }
    }
}

The swipe actions allow adding/removing items to the categories from the overview. This is through the modelContext on purpose, to see if the updates are coming through to the SwiftUI view. From the overview this works flawlessly.
When tapping a category, the CategoryDetail view is presented. Here is where my issues are occurring.
struct CategoryDetail: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    let category: Category
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                LabeledContent("Item Count", value: "\(category.items.count)")
            }
            
            Section {
                ForEach(category.items) { item in
                    Text("Item at \(item.timestamp, format: .dateTime)")
                        .swipeActions {
                            Button("Remove", systemImage: "trash", role: .destructive) {
                                modelContext.delete(item)
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            
            Section {
                Button("Add Item", systemImage: "plus") {
                    modelContext.insert(Item(
                        timestamp: Date(),
                        category: category
                    ))
                }
                Button("Remove Item", systemImage: "minus") {
                    if let lastItem = category.items.last {
                        modelContext.delete(lastItem)
                    }
                }
                Button("Edit Name", systemImage: "pencil") {
                    category.name.append("!")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(category.name)
    }
}

Here are a couple of ways to mutate the data. To start with there are buttons to add/remove items, when tapping these the items are added/removed, but the data in the view isn't updated.
Swiping to delete leads to the same result; although the row will disappear, that's just the SwiftUI behaviour and doesn't reflect the data in the view correctly, as the count stays the same.
If I go back to the overview and back to the detail the new data is available. Tapping "Edit Name" also updates the whole view, loading the new items as well. So the data seems to be there, it just not triggers SwiftUI view updates.
I have tried several things. Two of them did come close, as the result was what I expected but none of them were great solutions in my eyes:

Passing items separately to the detail view, this caused the view to update immediately when there were changes.
Have a @Query for items in the detail view. Tried adding predicate to filter for the category, couldn’t get this to work, but just having the query in there did already trigger view updates.

Any thoughts on how to get this to work as expected?

Use Bindable when the object can be modified, @Bindable category: Category.

@JoakimDanielson I have seen that suggestion a couple times of times and tried it. Unfortunately without success. Will edit my question to add what I tried as well.

You also have the possibility to listen to notifications from ModelContext, willSave and didSave. The latter is probably the best one.

I tried to reproduce this but I don't even understand how the UI is supposed to work, maybe because I mostly do macOS work.

try this approach for adding/removing the Item directly to the category in your CategoryDetail,
such that the UI is updated:
.swipeActions {
     Button("Remove", systemImage: "trash", role: .destructive) {
         if let index = category.items.firstIndex(of: item) {
             category.items.remove(at: index)
         }
     }
 }


 Button("Add Item", systemImage: "plus") {
     category.items.append(Item(timestamp: Date(), category: category))
 }

 Button("Remove Last", systemImage: "minus") {
     category.items.removeLast()
 }

and using
@Model
final class Item {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    @Relationship(inverse: \Category.items)
    var category: Category?   // <--- here
    
    init(timestamp: Date, category: Category) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
        self.category = category
    }
}

EDIT-1
If you are concerned about the extra code looking up the item in the array for the index
in the .swipeActions,
you can just add a function in the Category as shown in this example code.
Note that the add and delete are automatically performed and persisted in the DB.
 .swipeActions {
     Button("Remove", systemImage: "trash", role: .destructive) {
         category.delete(item) // <--- here
     }
 }

with
@Model
 final class Category {
     var name: String
     var items: [Item] = []
     
     init(name: String) {
         self.name = name
     }
     
     // --- here
     func delete(_ item: Item) {
         if let index = items.firstIndex(of: item) {
             items.remove(at: index)
         }
     }
 }
 


I did try this, it does solve the case of the examples. But that does make it more complex already, as you’d have to look up the item in the array for the index. In the real implementation it would also add data from another screen, and potentially not user initiated from an external source. So my goal is to have it updated from the model context, not by modifying the model in memory.

Updated my answer taking your concern about the extra code to look up the index of the Item.
Note, that in other screens there is no reason you could not use the model context to add
or delete items,
even if it is not user initiated and comes from an external source.
